Derivatives of Linear Functions vs Derivatives of Non-Linear Functions?
Consider a linear function $f(x_1, x_2)$.
$$ f(x_1, x_2) = a_0 + a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_1x_2 $$
From here we can see the basic fact that the partial derivative (e.g. with respect to $x_1$) is equal to a change in $f(x_1, x_2)$ from a $1$ unit change in $x_1$:
$$ \frac{df(x_1,x_2)}{dx_1} = a_1 + a_3x_2 $$
$$z = f(x_1 +1,x_2) - f(x_1, x_2) $$
$$ z = [a_0 + a_1(x_1 + 1) + a_2x_2 + a_3(x_1 + 1)x_2] - [(a_0 + a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_1x_2)] =  a_1 + a_3x_2  $$
$$z = \frac{df(x_1, x_2)}{dx_1} = a_1 + a_3x_2 $$
However, this is not necessarily true for curved surfaces:
$$ g(x_1, x_2) =  a_0 + a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_1x_2 $$
$$ \frac{\partial g(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} (a_0 + a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_1x_2) $$
$$ \frac{\partial g(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1} = 2a_1x_1 + a_3x_2 $$
Now, when looking at the same difference:
$$ z = g(x_1 + 1, x_2) - g(x_1, x_2) $$
$$ g(x_1 + 1, x_2) = a_0 + a_1(x_1 + 1)^2 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3(x_1 + 1)x_2 $$
$$ g(x_1 + 1, x_2) = a_0 + a_1x_1^2 + 2a_1x_1 + a_1 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_1x_2 + a_3x_2 $$
$$ z = [a_0 + a_1x_1^2 + 2a_1x_1 + a_1 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_1x_2 + a_3x_2] - [a_0 + a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_2^2 + a_3x_1x_2] $$
$$ z = 2a_1x_1 + a_1 + a_3x_2 $$
Thus, we can see:
$$ 2a_1x_1 + a_3x_2 = 2a_1x_1 + a_1 + a_3x_2 $$
$$ \frac{\partial g(x_1, x_2)}{\partial x_1} \neq z$$
A $1$ unit change is not necessarily equal to the derivative - rather, only a very small change is equal to the derivative.
Does this principle in math have a name?

You might want to look at the idea of divided differences and Newton interpolation formulas.

This is single variable calculus. Your example is too complicated to see what's going on.
For any differentiable function $f$, the derivative is the limit of the difference quotient, so for small $h$
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h } \approx f'(x)
$$
so
$$
f(x+h) - f(x) \approx f'(x)h .
$$
Geometrically, that says the tangent line provides a good approximation to $f(x+h)$ when $h$ is small.
When $f$ is a linear function the tangent line at any point on the graph is the graph itself, and
$$
f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h .
$$
In particular, that's true when $h=1$.

As a matter of fact, yes, this principle does have a name. The limit definition of the derivative, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$$ is just the idea of taking your difference over an interval ($z$ in your question), and letting that interval shrink towards $0$, which calculates the slope of a line tangent to the original function at a particular point. This limit definition is known as first principles. All your basic derivative rules stem from this definition, power, chain, product, exponentials, the lot. We just don't use it much because for even relatively simple functions it can become an absolute mess. As for straight lines, the reason it works for $h=1$ is that the tangent line to a straight line is that same straight line at any point, and the average of $2$ points on a straight line is another point on that line, so the limit is already correct even before you let $h\rightarrow0$.
